# SQL Alchemy deleting association from many to many

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I know this question has already been asked by I could not find a clean solution.

My problem is simple: I have a table with a many to many association. Where users have many workspaces and workspaces have many users.

```
invitations_table = db.Table('invitations', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='cascade'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('workspace_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('workspace.id', ondelete='cascade'), primary_key=True)
```

)

Now my two class are declared like that:

```
class Workspace(db.Model):

   id           = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
...
   u_invited       = db.relationship("User",
       secondary       = invitations_table,
       cascade         = 'all',
       back_populates  = "w_invited")

class User(db.Model):
   id           = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
 ...
   w_invited    = db.relationship("Workspace",
        secondary       = invitations_table,
        back_populates  = "u_invited")
```

Now, If I delete my workspace, I can't cascade the deletion on the associative table as well:

```
   def delete_all_workspace(self):
       workspace = Workspace.query.filter_by(owner=self)

    # for w in  workspace.all():
    #       w.u_invited.clear()

       succeed = workspace.delete()
       db.session.commit()
```

The problem is: I need, as some people suggest, to manually loop into my list of objects then call clear() in order to not get this exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) update or delete on table "workspace" violates foreign key constraint "invitations_workspace_id_fkey" on table "invitations"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(142) is still referenced from table "invitations".
```

I though ondelete='cascade' will be enough to tell sqlalchemy to delete the associative table as well but that's not working as expected.

My question is: Is there a way to tell SQLAlchemy to clear the associative table invitations as well without having the burden to clear it manually?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Should that be `cascade='all, delete-orphan'` (and maybe also `passive_deletes=True`)?

Comment: do you change your database foreign key constraints about `ondelete='cascade'`?